# How do I update a python package to a git commit version?

Tags: python, pip

How do I update my xnat python package to this specific commit version?

https://gitlab.com/radiology/infrastructure/xnatpy/-/commit/f58f04a2eeae62cd8f0631d213c6ff5552c44a70

When I tried `pip install xnat` it doesn't include this update and I was wondering how I can include it

Answer (score 2):

You should run

```
pip install git+https://gitlab.com/radiology/infrastructure/xnatpy.git@f58f04a2eeae62cd8f0631d213c6ff5552c44a70#egg=xnat
```

PyPI will install package (egg) named `xnat` from repository `https://gitlab.com/radiology/infrastructure/xnatpy.git` at commit `f58f04a2eeae62cd8f0631d213c6ff5552c44a70`

Comment: is this the same for conda?

Comment: You would have to install pip via conda and then run this command